# Ошибка при подключении к серверу. OSError: [WinError 10048] Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)

Tags: python, сокет, websocket, bind

Приветстсвую! Захотел написать сервер, который способен принимать большое количество соединений, кажое в отдельном процессе(для примера). Вот код из файла server_1.py:

```
# создание сокета, таймауты и обработка ошибок
# сервер
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process


def data_handler(connection):
    print('Starting handle')
    with connection:
        while True:
            try:
                data = connection.recv(1024)
            except socket.timeout:
                print("close connection by timeout")
                break

            if not data:
                break
            print(data.decode("utf8"))


with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 10001))
    sock.listen()
    print('socket забайден')
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        conn.settimeout(5)  # timeout := None|0|gt 0
        p = Process(target=data_handler, args=(conn,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Клиент - работа в консоли:
import socket
sock = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', 10001))

В итоге вылетает исключение в программе server_1.py вида:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python_code\server_1.py", line 23, in <module>
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 10001))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)
```

Я прочитал, пишут, что я не могу два раза bind'нуть один и тот же адрес. Но ведь разве я не один раз его bind'ю при запуске server_1.py? Почему `socket.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 10001))` тоже bind'ит?

Дело в том, что в server_2.py всё работает нормально и исключение не вылетает:

```
import socket

with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 10001))
    sock.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print("connected client:", addr)
        # процесс или поток для обработки соединения
        with conn:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                print(data.decode("utf8"))
```

Но почему тут не вылетает OSError: [WinError 10048]? Дайте пожалуйста чёткую разницу между этими серверами. И подскажите, что не так в первом случае?

Comment: Новый процесс при запуске первым делом импортирует файл server_1.py, а при этом выполняются все top-level инструкции, включая блок `with socket.socket() as sock`.

Comment: То есть, чтобы использовать Process в этом примере, мне нужно импортировать функцию `data_handler` из другого файла? Это поможет избежать повторного запуска кода из файла server_1.py?

Comment: В документации рекомендуют top-level инструкции завернуть в блок `if __name__ == "__main__"` - это должно решить проблему.